# Imacro DataSource error

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am trying to create a file that macro that will read from a .csv file but i keep getting this error

```
    RuntimeError: Data source file does not exist, line 1 (Error code: -930)
```

here is my .js file

```
    var load;
    load =  "CODE:";
    load +=  "SET !DATASOURCE Config.csv" + "\n";
    load +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2" + "\n";
    load +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\n";
    load +=  "SET !extract {{!col2}}" + "\n";

    var startPageNumber = "";
    var Refund;
    var Donation;
    var x = 3;

    for(i=1;i<x;i++) {

        iimSet("i",i);
        iimPlay(load);
        startPageNumber = iimGetLastExtract(0);
        alert(startPageNumber);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that I needed 2 slashes "\" and I needed to specify the path
OLD:

```
        load +=  "SET !DATASOURCE Config.csv" + "\n";
```

NEW

```
        load +=  "SET !DATASOURCE C:\\Config.csv" + "\n";
```